# Express: express-unless breaking with simple example

Tags: node.js, express

https://github.com/jfromaniello/express-unless

**Two questions..**

1. Any idea why this does not work?
2. It appears this library is abandoned. Are there any other alternatives?

   ```
   handleExpiredTokens.unless({
     path: [{
     url: '/foo',
     methods: ['POST']
    }]
   });


   function handleExpiredTokens(err, req, res, next) {
    // stuff
   }

    handleExpiredTokens.unless = unless;

   module.exports = handleExpiredTokens;
   ```

handleExpiredTokens runs on every request including POST /foo

getting a `protectWithCSRF.unless is not a function`

Comment: obviously any random middleware won't have a function "unless" as its property. You should do something like this handleExpiredTokens.unless = require('express-unless'); Something you can find here in readme.md : https://github.com/jfromaniello/express-unless

Comment: i'm adding it in per the intructions

Comment: In any case, `handleExpiredTokens.unless = unless;` should be declared _before_ calling it at `handleExpiredTokens.unless({path:[...`. About alternatives: do the condition manually at the route declaration, instead of spreading route-related logics in all your files.